MySQL error: Unknown table 'meta_value' in 'MULTI DELETE'
In phpmyAdmin I would like to DELETE the content of meta_value fields in wp_postmeta table, if the content has a certain string.
When I'm using SELECT to show the rows first, my code is working and all rows with the founded string are shown correct. But if I use DELETE instead of SELECT, I'm getting the following error:
Unknown table 'meta_value' in 'MULTI DELETE'
This is my code:
DELETE pm.meta_value FROM wp_postmeta pm 
LEFT JOIN wp_posts wp ON wp.ID = pm.post_id 
WHERE wp.post_type = 'person' 
AND pm.meta_key = 'gallery' 
AND pm.meta_value LIKE '%mystring%';

What did I do wrong? Thanks in advance!

That's not the correct multi-table syntax for mysql see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/delete.html

I would like to DELETE the content of meta_value fields in wp_postmeta table, if the content has a certain string. DELETE can be applied to the whole object (row). You need to alter current value in one column only? this is UPDATE. If you need to delete the whole row nevertheless then you must specify not the column but the table which the row must be removed from - DELETE pm FROM wp_postmeta pm ... And anycase your LEFT JOIN is by fact INNER JOIN due to the conditions in WHERE - so use .. INNER JOIN wp_posts wp .., and the server shouldn't perform unneeded excess work.

Perfect, thank you. Update solved the problem  :-)

As @Akina said, the problem was, that I used DELETE instead UPDATE, to modify or delete a single field.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
